# findOneAndUpdate is not working inside array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to update the document in the MongoDB collection but it's not working for me. Here is the function all fields come to the backend.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a6b381c13a090c70fc21b6"),
    "processNumber" : "FEE 082517",
    "System" : "abc",    
    "TaxAmount" : 0,
    "TaxPercent" : 0,
    "Currency" : "USD",
    "ProcessData" : [ 
        
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59ee2873b1621419a03fba6c"),
            "KDSID" : "1db1d4b8-61bc-45eb-bf6d-15af1e391df5"
            
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59ee2873b1621419a03fba6d"),
            "KDSID" : "aa9ccaf3-a638-4013-afdc-ccf0a39361e8"
            
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59ee2873b1621419a03fba6e"),
            "KDSID" : "4c5e32a7-e2fb-4fe9-998f-e22602e46dba"
        }
        {
            "Name" : "2017 Calc.xlsx",
            "FileID" : "59ee2873b1621419a03fb9b7",
            "_id" : ObjectId("59ee2873b1621419a03fba75")
        }
    ]     
       
  }
```

**Query:**

```
db.process.findOneAndUpdate(
   { 'ProcessData._id': ObjectId("59ee2873b1621419a03fba75"),'ProcessData.FileID': { '$exists': true, '$ne': null }},
   { $set: { 'ProcessData.$.IsFailed': "Yes" } }
  
)
```

When I run the above query IsFailed is not updating. can you please advise?
I have tried in node and MongoDB and it's not working.

If ProcessData._id matches with the given id and ProcessData.FileID exist we have to set IsFailed **Yes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's my version with `$elemMatch`

```
db.process.updateOne(
    {
        ProcessData: {
            $elemMatch: {
                _id: ObjectId("59ee2873b1621419a03fba75"),
                FileID: {
                    $exists: true,
                    $ne: null
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $set: { "ProcessData.$.IsFaild": "Yes" }
    })
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/3LBlw9kA6Gl

Comment: it's working but what is the diff bw findOneAndUpdate and updateOne

Comment: @itsme use `findOneAndUpdate` if you need to retrieve the document after updating. if you don't care about retrieving, then use `updateOne`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use arrayFilter when you modify the array.

```
db.collectionName.updateOne(
    { 
        'ProcessData._id': ObjectId("59ee2873b1621419a03fba75"),
        'ProcessData.FileID': { '$exists': true, '$ne': null }
    },
    {
        $set:{"ProcessData.$[p].isFailed": "Yes"}},
    {
      arrayFilters:[{"p._id":ObjectId("59ee2873b1621419a03fba75")}]
    }
)
```

Comment: I have to check ProcessData.FileID exists or not. if exist only I have to update

Comment: it's not working. {
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "matchedCount" : 0.0,
    "modifiedCount" : 0.0
}

Comment: Do u need to check `$ne:null` since exists true? If u remove, it will work

Comment: I need $ne:null

Answer (score 0):

You're querying through an array of **embedded documents**, and hence by using **elemMatch** to find the specific **id** and perform needed operation on that document should be implemented for example as below:

```
db.process.updateOne(
{
    ProcessData: {
        $elemMatch: {
            _id: 
            ObjectId("59ee2873b1621419a03fba75"),
        }
    }
},
{
    "ProcessData.FileID": {
        $exists: true,
        $ne: null
    }
},
{
    $set: {
        "ProcessData.$.IsFailed": "Yes"
    }
})
```

Comment: Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators